# PIC24FJ256GA410, UART interrupt, freeze after enable

Tags: pic, uart, interrupts

I'm fairly new to PIC and MCUs. My board has PIC24FJ256GA410 MCU with external 3.6864 MHz crystal. I'd like to use UART1 for debugging purposes. Below is my `main()` that just initializes UART1. However, once I program the MCU with code that calls `InitUART()`, my board becomes *unprogrammable*. Every attempt at programming it gives me **Failed to program device** error. Also, sometimes, it writes something like this into console:

```
Address: 278 Expected Value: eb0000 Received Value: a90000
```

or

```
The programmer could not be started: Could not connect to tool hardware: ICD3PlatformTool, com.microchip.mplab.mdbcore.ICD3Tool.ICD3DbgToolManager
```

I'm using Microchip ICD3 and MPLAB X IDE for programming. If I comment out the `InitUART()` call, I can program the board again. What's the problem with my code? It's mostly identical with the code from *dsPIC33-PIC24 FRM - UART* datasheet except I don't write default values. Also, I've seen other examples on the Internet and my is quite similar. I configured only the output pin.

EDIT: After I comment assignment to `_RP11R` in `InitUART()` function, I can successfully program the board every time. AFAIK, I need to select pin for the UART1 perpherial too. But once I set the `_RP11R`, the board becomes *unprogrammable* (and UART1 doesn't work anyway). I'm pretty sure the `RP11` is the correct UART output pin.

```
#include <xc.h>

#define FOSC 3686400
#define FCY (FOSC/2)

#include <libpic30.h>

#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF
#pragma config GWRP = OFF
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF
#pragma config ICS = PGx3
#pragma config FWPSA = PR128
#pragma config WDTPS = PS2048
#pragma config FCKSM = CSECMD
#pragma config OSCIOFCN = OFF
#pragma config POSCMOD = XT
#pragma config FNOSC = PRI

#define BAUDRATE 115200

static void InitUART(void)
{
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & 0xbf);
    _RP11R = _RPOUT_U1TX;
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x40);
    U1BRG = (int) (FCY/(16 * BAUDRATE) - 1);
    _U1TXIE = 1;
    U1MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;
    U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1;
}


void __attribute__((__interrupt__, auto_psv)) _U1TXInterrupt(void)
{
    _U1TXIF = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    TRISBbits.TRISB3 = 0;
    LATBbits.LATB3 = 0;

    InitUART();

    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        LATBbits.LATB3 = i;
        i = !i;
        __delay_ms(500);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check if your UART pins are not the ones that you are using to program the board i.e. PGEC/PGED pins are not configured as UART1 pins.

Comment: Nope. In the code, I configure only the output pin. If I understand correctly, by default, peripheral output pins are disconnected and peripheral input pins are tied to Vdd.

Comment: PGECx/PGEDx are on different RPx pins on my MCU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had bad cable connections. TX pin was connected to the ground.

My colleague says: *If it doesn't work check the cables. If the cables are okay and it still doesn't work, check the cables again.*